# How to get item in ItemDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Hope everything is fine.

How can I find control ItemDataBound

I have this

```
<telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" 
           PageSize="3">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" AlwaysVisible="true"></PagerStyle>
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="ID"  >
                     <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="false" />
                     <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="36px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ImageName" UniqueName="ImageName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Width="300px" ID="txbName" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Requiredfieldvalidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txbName"
                                ErrorMessage="Please, enter a name!" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="30%"></HeaderStyle>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Url" HeaderText="Url" UniqueName="Url">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1"  ImageUrl='<%#Request.ApplicationPath + "/images/" + Eval("Url") %>'
                                AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Height="80px" Width="80px" ToolTip='<%#Eval("Url") %>'
                                AlternateText='<%#Eval("Url") %>'></telerik:RadBinaryImage>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadAsyncUpload  RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="AsyncUpload1" 
                                AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" MaxFileSize="1048576">
                            </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


                    
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Status" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Status")) %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Status" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Status")) %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>



                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Title" UniqueName="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltitle" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Width="300px" ID="txtTitle" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'>
                        </telerik:RadTextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="30%"></HeaderStyle>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                     

                  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn  HeaderText="Album" UniqueName="Album">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%data source=cr-test-db01;initial catalog=CRAWebsite;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssword; Application Name=CRA; %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Album]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


                        <telerik:RadDropDownList  RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Width="300px" ID="ddlAlbums">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem  runat="server" Text="A" Value="A" />
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList   RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Width="300px" ID="ddlAlbums">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem  runat="server" Text="A" Value="A" />
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="30%"></HeaderStyle>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>



                </Columns>
                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn ButtonType="FontIconButton">
                    </EditColumn>
                </EditFormSettings>
                <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True"></PagerStyle>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
            {
                GridCommandItem item = (GridCommandItem)e.Item;
                var RadDropDownList = (RadDropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAlbums");
                (RadDropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAlbums"); show null why ???

            }


            var albums = DBLayer.DbLayer.GetAlbums();
            foreach (var item in albums.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in albums.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                DropDownListItem item2 = new DropDownListItem();
                item2.Text = row["Content_Name_a"].ToString();
                item2.DropDownList.DataTextField = row["Content_Name_a"].ToString();
                item2.DropDownList.DataValueField = row["Id"].ToString();
            }


        }
```

Comment: Does `FindControl` not work?

Comment: Where is `ddlAlbums` in `RadGrid1`?

Comment: @VDWWD yes in Radgrid1

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure its a item type, not command item

```
     if((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||  (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
     { 

       var RadDropDownList = (RadDropDownList)e.item.FindControl("ddlAlbums");

        if(RadDropDownList != null)
        {
            //do what you need here
         }
     }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.onitemdatabound?view=netframework-4.8